# Error: "not found in axis" when droping list of index values

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to drop two days every year from a dataframe with hourly values from 6am-8pm for dates from the 15.07 to 20.10. Therefore, I created a list with all the dates that should be dropped like this:

```py
drop_list =[] 

for i in range(0,6):
    Year = 1999 + i
    drop_list.append(str(Year)+'-07-15')
    drop_list.append(str(Year)+'-07-16')
```

My data looks like this:

[image: data]

When I now call:

```
y = y.drop(drop_list)
```

I get:

> KeyError: "['1999-07-15' '1999-07-16' '2000-07-15' '2000-07-16' '2001-07-15'\n '2001-07-16' '2002-07-15' '2002-07-16' '2003-07-15' '2003-07-16'\n '2004-07-15' '2004-07-16'] not found in axis"

Any suggestions what I am missing?

Comment: Based on your screenshot, looks like your index is a datetime object and you are passing a list of strings to df.drop.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to drop from a datetime index, you need to pass datetimes.

E.g.

```
>>> s = pd.Series([1,2,3], index=pd.to_datetime(['2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03']))

>>> s
2020-01-01    1
2020-01-02    2
2020-01-03    3
dtype: int64

>>> s.drop(pd.to_datetime(['2020-01-01']))
2020-01-02    2
2020-01-03    3
dtype: int64
```

In your case, `y.drop(pd.to_datetime(drop_list))`  might work.